# AppleScript - Comparing a list for works that contains any part of another list

Tags: list, applescript, compare

Input:

```
set firstList to {'red ball','blue','yellow'}
set secondList to {'grasshopper','yellowjacket','blueberry','redball'}
```

Output:

```
{'yellowjacket','blueberry','redball'}
```

What's the best way to accomplish something like this? Basically I'm looking for ANY similarity between the items within each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set matchList to {}
set firstList to {"red ball ", "blue", "yellow"}
set secondList to {"grasshopper", "yellowjacket", "blueberry", "redball"}

repeat with aItem in firstList
    set myTerm to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of aItem & " | sed -E 's/  */ ?/g'"
    repeat with bItem in secondList
        try
            set end of matchList to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of bItem & " | grep -E " & quoted form of myTerm)
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

return matchList
```

EDIT

```
    set matchList to {}
set firstList to {"jamesdoe","jackknow","henryrod"}
set secondList to {"James Doe", "Jack Know", "John Matthews"}

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {""}}
repeat with aItem in firstList
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    set myTerm to text items of aItem
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" ?"}
    set myTerm to myTerm as text
    repeat with bItem in secondList
        try
            set end of matchList to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of bItem & " | grep -Ei " & quoted form of myTerm)
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

set text item delimiters to TID
return matchList
```

EDIT 2

```
set matchList to {}
set firstList to {"jamesdoe", "jackknow", "henryrod"}
set secondList to {"James Doe", "Jack Know", "John Matthews"}

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {""}}
repeat with aItem in firstList
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    set myTerm to text items of aItem
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" ?"}
    set myTerm to myTerm as text
    repeat with bItem in secondList
        try
            do shell script "echo " & quoted form of bItem & " | grep -Ei " & quoted form of myTerm
            set end of matchList to (aItem's contents)
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

set text item delimiters to TID
return matchList
```

Comment: Wow! I should really try to understand `sed` more... this is exactly what I was looking for! Having a bit of an issue though.. I'm trying to incorporate with... `set list1 to {"jamesdoe","jackknow","henryrod"}` and `set list2 to {"James Doe","Jack Know","John Matthews"` that would return `{"jamesdoe","jackknow"}`..

Comment: Will you elaborate on that a bit ?

Comment: Sorry, hit `enter` too quick.. `set list1 to {"jamesdoe","jackknow","henryrod"}` and `set list2 to {"James Doe","Jack Know","John Matthews"` that would return `{"jamesdoe","jackknow"}`

Comment: Sorry if I misphrased the above comment, I can't figure out how to get `{"jamesdoe", "jackknow"}` instead of the `{"James Doe", "Jack Know"}`